# Анимированая смена квадратов

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как сделать плавное появление квадратов,a так же переключение квадратов по нажатию на кнопки.

```js
    function autoLoopSlider(obj, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(obj == ".border_line.end"){
           $(obj).addClass("end-next");
           $(obj).removeClass("end");
        }
        if(obj == ".border_line.end-next"){
           $(obj).addClass("end");
           $(obj).removeClass("end-next");
        } 
    }, time);
};

setInterval(function(){ autoLoopSlider(".border_line.end", 2500); autoLoopSlider(".border_line.end-next", 2000);},3000);

function buttonActive(button){
    $(document).on("click", button , function(){
        if($(".border_line").hasClass("end")){
           $(".border_line").removeClass("end");
           $(".border_line").addClass("end-next"); 
        }
        else {
            $(".border_line").addClass("end");
            $(".border_line").removeClass("end-next");
        }
    })
}
buttonActive(".button_1");
buttonActive(".button_2");
```

```css
.end {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.end-next {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border_line end"></div>
//переключение квадратов
<button class="button_1">b1</button>
<button class="button_2">b2</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, добавить `transition` блокам меняющим класс:

```js
function autoLoopSlider(obj, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(obj == ".border_line.end"){
           $(obj).addClass("end-next");
           $(obj).removeClass("end");
        }
        if(obj == ".border_line.end-next"){
           $(obj).addClass("end");
           $(obj).removeClass("end-next");
        } 
    }, time);
};

setInterval(function(){ autoLoopSlider(".border_line.end", 2500); autoLoopSlider(".border_line.end-next", 2000);},3000);

function buttonActive(button){
    $(document).on("click", button , function(){
        if($(".border_line").hasClass("end")){
           $(".border_line").removeClass("end");
           $(".border_line").addClass("end-next"); 
        }
        else {
            $(".border_line").addClass("end");
            $(".border_line").removeClass("end-next");
        }
    })
}
buttonActive(".button_1");
buttonActive(".button_2");
```

```css
.end {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
.end-next {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border_line end"></div>
//переключение квадратов
<button class="button_1">b1</button>
<button class="button_2">b2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Анимация http://www.jooom.ru/toster/toster_18.html

Переключалка блоков http://www.jooom.ru/toster/toster_6.html